# How to append star character * in StringBuilder?

Tags: java, sql, special-characters, stringbuilder

I am writing a program for sql database and need to build a `select` query based on selected columns. When no columns are selected I want to use `select * from` syntax. How do I append * to StringBuilder?

```
ArrayList<String> columns;
StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder("select ");

... 

if (columns == null || columns.size() == 0) {
    queryBuilder.append(Character.toString ((char) 42));
} else {
    for (String name : columns) {
        queryBuilder.append(name);
        queryBuilder.append(", ");
    }
}
queryBuilder.setLength(queryBuilder.length() - 2);
queryBuilder.append(" from ");
queryBuilder.append(tableName);
```

I also tried `("*")` `("\*")` `("\\*")` `('*')` `((char)42)` but none of those work. The output I get from StringBuilder is `select from tableName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
queryBuilder.append('*');
```

The problem you have is with this line:

```
queryBuilder.setLength(queryBuilder.length() - 2);
```

It affects the whole `StringBuilder` despite if it has appended a single character or all the column names, when it should only affect the concatenation of the column names. Move this line to here:

```
} else {
    for (String name : columns) {
        queryBuilder.append(name);
        queryBuilder.append(", ");
    }
    queryBuilder.setLength(queryBuilder.length() - 2);
}
//queryBuilder.setLength(queryBuilder.length() - 2);
queryBuilder.append(" from ");
queryBuilder.append(tableName);
```

Or even better, use something like [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) or [`Collectors#joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-) that will do the work of the `for` for you and not append the extra `", "` in the end.

If you're using Java 7 or prior, then I recommend to use [`StringUtils#join`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Object[],%20char%29) from Apache Commons that will do the join of the column names for you.

Comment: thank you, I forgot about the line at the bottom... I also replaced the loop with `queryBuilder.append(String.join(", ", columns));` and it's working flawlessly now.